# How to replace string with single quotes?

Tags: php, javascript, pyrocms

My Date value is  2013/06/04 - 2013/06/06 , i want to replace it with '2013/06/04' And '2013/06/06' how can i do it?
I tried giving

```
var value = $("#date_range").val().replace('-','\'');
```

but i am getting escape character?

Comment: I'm not sure what you *want* to happen. After running this, I get "2013/06/04 ' 2013/06/06", which seems expected

Comment: There are probably many here who could help you if you clarify your question. Do you realize what `.replace()` is doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt wouldn't wrap the outer sides of the dates in quotes anyway, so I don't think that's what you're looking for. Try:

```
var str = "2013/06/04 - 2013/06/06";
var dates = str.split(" - ");
var value = "'"+dates.join("' and '")+"'";
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVx4e/)

Results in `'2013/06/04' and '2013/06/06'`

Comment: i think i like your answer a little better than mine. :)

Comment: Well, thank you very muchly! I think there'll be a world of pain if the dates aren't formatted just right when put into it, but that's up to the OP I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot dKen, Appreciated a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var val = $('#date_range')[0].value.split(' - '),
    finalval;

for(i=2;i--;){
    val[i] = "'"+val[i]+"'";
}

finalval = val.join(' - ');
```

This should wrap the newval in single quotes like you want, and you can just use `finalval` as the wrapped version of original `val`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the escape character is coming from the jQuery .val() call. You may want to look into valHooks.